# Better Exposed Filter Module(bef) doesn't work with hierarchical taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm using better exposed filter module, and trying to build a filter based on a hierarchical taxonomy. But I can't work it out. Whatever how many terms in the taxonomy, the filter only show two radios: `-any-` and ``(empty). Like this:
[image]

Do I miss something?

You can follow my steps: on a new drupal site, the default content type 'article' has a field named `Tags`, using the default taxonomy `tags`. So I build a simple hierarchy like this:
[image]

Then I create a new page view for content type 'article', add the `Tags` field to `FILTER CRITERIA` and set `Dropdown` with `Show hierarchy in dropdown`. 
[image]

And set the display to `Nested Checkboxes/Radios Buttons` in `BEF settings`.
[image]

Visit the view page, only 2 radios are shown: `-Any-` and ``(empty). 
[image]

I have try other display setting in `BEF settings`:

- Default Select List: will show all 6 options in a dropdown with `-` prefix, it's ok
- Checkboxes/Radios Buttons: will show 2 radios, `-All-` and ``(empty).
- Links: will show all 6 links with `-` prefix, , it's ok

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange that the default option shows the correct info (dropdown with dash-prefixed options) but the BEF nested option doesn't work correctly. I just tried this using a clean build and a similar taxonomy and it was displaying correctly:

[image]

Since this is my dev machine, I'm using the latest -dev releases of CTools (7.x-1.x), Views (7.x-3.x) and BEF (7.x-3.x). Can you try your site with the latest BEF to start with and possibly Views/CTools, if that doesn't fix thing?

Finally, if all else fails, feel free to open an issue in the BEF issue queue (which I'm hoping to give some attention to this month -- New Year's resolutions and all...). Be sure to include an export of the view and content type(s) needed to reproduce the problem.

Hope that helps.